# how make excutable for my java application with JDeveloper

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I want to create an excutable file for my java project, previous time I do it by Jbuilder or netbean as I remember but I dont know how I should do it in JDeveloper to make Excutable file(EXE file)

please advice me, please describe clearly...

EDIT:
It's simple desktop application.it is not web application....

EDIT2:
I remove that part for checking argument and run my program I face with this problem:
what should I do?

```
Executing: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\SourceManagmentTools\Client\deploy\SMT.exe
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdeveloper/layout/VerticalFlowLayout
    at Main.GUI.SmMainFrame.<init>(SmMainFrame.java:134)
    at Main.GUI.SmRun.<init>(SmRun.java:25)
    at Main.GUI.SmRun$1.run(SmRun.java:82)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdeveloper.layout.VerticalFlowLayout
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: What kind of project is it? I doubt you can do something like this for a web project.

Comment: I put some note,it is simple desktop application not web project...

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)?

Regarding your configuration problem, the Launch4J [documetation](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Additional_jvm_options) says:

Additional JVM options at runtime

> When you create a wrapper or launcher
>   all configuration details are compiled
>   into the executable and cannot be
>   changed without recreating it or
>   hacking with a resource editor.
>   Launch4j 2.1.2 introduces a new
>   feature that allows to pass additional
>   JVM options at runtime from an
>   .l4j.ini file. Now you can specify the
>   options in the configuration file, ini
>   file or in both, but you cannot
>   override them. The ini file's name
>   must correspond to the executable's
>   (myapp.exe : myapp.l4j.ini). The
>   arguments should be separated with
>   spaces or new lines, environment
>   variable expansion is supported, for
>   example:

```
# Launch4j runtime config
-Dswing.aatext=true
-Dsomevar="%SOMEVAR%"
-Xms16m
```

Other alternatives that you may consider are [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/),[WinRun4J](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks it is very good software but I have same problem that above mention when I run my exe file now one pop up message that I created will appear regarding missing arguments but when I try to pass parameter no action!?? previous I pass parameter with JDeveloper now :(

Comment: @rima The Launch4j documentation explains how to address the issue. I have updated the post.

Comment: So it is not useful because I want send a username to my program form a Oracle form....

Comment: Does it really need to be an exe? because you can easily create a batch file that your users can invoke in windows pretty much the same as you do with an exe. And there you can more easily control arguments.

Comment: You are missing classes in your class path. I have also suggested two other tools named JSmooth and WinRun4J.

Answer (score 0):

If your desktop application has a GUI, and you can distribute it from a site, look to [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

JWS provides a 'one-click' installation option for the end user, automatic updates, desktop integration, splash screens and much more.  It is part of the standard Java(1) distribution (since 1.4.2) & is supported by Oracle.

---

(1) JWS works with standard Jar files - no exe needed, which means it will work on *nix & Mac.

Comment: do u know how I can pass parameter to a jar file?

Comment: What is an 'Oracle form'?  I looked at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/overview/index.html & can still not make head nor tail of it.

Comment: "do u know how I can pass parameter to a jar file?"  Using JWS it is easy - use the `argument` element within the `application-desc` element.  See [`application-desc` Element](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#application_desc) for details.  BTW - spelling words like 'you' as 'u' will win no friends around these parts.  We have full keyboards and wide (enough) bandwidth to spell **all 3** letters of such a word.

Comment: I just looked for a simple way...:(

Comment: when I run my program javaw -jar myfile.jar it is working, but when I call it like javaw -jar myfile.jar parameter1  there is no action from command prompt

Comment: @rima "I try to download it"  Huh?  What did you try to download? "I just looked for a simple way."  A good deployment (of an app. to random end-users) is never easy.  The 'simple way' is to hire someone that has experience with it.

Comment: @rima: "when I call it like javaw -jar myfile.jar parameter1 there is no action" Note that [javaw](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) is **not the same as** [javaws](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/javaws.html).  The first is launching java without a visible CLI.  The second is for launching JWS based projects.  Note that `javaws` has no relevance to the end user, they click a link to get the app., we (developers) need `javaws` for testing our deployment.

Comment: @andrew 1st message: Thanks bro, I am better than my friends, and since a class of java charge me 1,200$ for 5 day I am not happy hire any person! So I prefer ask my question here

Comment: Would u describe more, an example, now I try to write some thing like javaws -jar myfile.jar parameter1      one pop up came and told me what is parameter!?would you help me with an example?

Comment: Also I dont want create jnlp file, please advice me

Comment: @rima "I dont want create jnlp file"  Yeah & I don't want borders, racism or militarism.  Point being, we don't always get what we want.  But since you have an IDE, I can recommend some little examples.  Visit my page on [JNLP API Examples](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html).  Each one has a downloadable archive that includes the Java source, JNLP file (most of which are quite simple) & an Ant style `build.xml` that any IDE can work with.  Give a few of those a try, starting with the one for the `BasicService`.

Comment: @rima "I am not happy hire any person!" (chuckle) Fair enough.  In fact I am surprised that nobody has yet berated me for daring to suggest hiring someone.  (It could be seen as a sideways attempt at soliciting work.)

Answer (score 0):

it so simple guys...
I solved my problem in this way...simplest way....

first of all check the version of java that installed in your client computer, you check by this command in CMD:
java -version

after you make sure about java version you need to make a bat file. [conflict in version maybe cause null except] after that you should know which external package u used in this project... for example I used 1 file for connecting to oracle database "ojdbc14" and the other for GUI, after that you can simply run your program or even pass parameter to them by just mention them at end of name of runable of your class:

```
java -client -classpath ojdbc14.jar;lipstikLF-1.1.jar;swing-layout.jar;smt.jar Main.GUI.SmRun rimrim
```

I guess those library we used in our project need also run, but I am not sure, I just suggest this work

```
java -client -classpath <name of you library>;<name of you library>;<name of your jar file> nameOfPackage.nameOfRunClass parameter[if any]
```

I will so appreciate if anybody add some useful info to this post